# Loading SessionSnapshot doesn't work, can't set cookie

Tags: php, cookies, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I've got problem with acceptance test using codecpetion.
I try to avoid login every time with snapshot, but every time I tries to run test I see:

```
 1. $I->loadSessionSnapshot("login")
...
 [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidCookieDomainException] You may only set cookies for the current domain
```

And logs from selenium server (notice that dot before domain in second line):

```
  [Selenium client Logs]
  10:28:09.7 INFO - org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle Done: [add cookie: device_view=full; expires=Cz, 16 cze 2016 12:00:00 CEST; path=/; domain=foo.example.com]
  10:28:09.8 INFO - org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle Executing: [add cookie: _gat_UA-58964912-1=1; expires=Pn, 16 maj 2016 10:38:03 CEST; path=/; domain=.foo.example.com])
  10:28:09.16 WARNING - org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle Exception thrown
  10:28:09.17 WARNING - org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle Exception: You may only set cookies for the current domain
  Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
  System info: host: 'foobar', ip: '123.456.78.90', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

What can I do?

Comment: You first need to set the domain by opening an URL with the same domain as the cookies.

Comment: @FlorentB. I'm on page example.com but there is also a cookie for all subdomains(I think that is what this dot mean) `.example.com`
I'm successfully logged on page, and save snapshot, but I;cant load it.